# Proving that two random variables are identically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to prove the following:

- Sample space $\Omega$ is from tossing two identical coins and $F$ is the power set of $\Omega$.
- Random variables X is the number of heads and Y is the number of tails.
- Prove that X and Y are identically distributed.

What I have done so far is that I drew two mappings between $\Omega$ and $R$, one for X and one for Y.

Then, I show that:

- $p(X=0)=1/4=p(Y=0)$
- $p(X=1)=1/2=p(Y=1)$
- $p(X=2)=1/4=p(Y=2)$

Do you think this is a mathematically rigorous proof? Is this sufficient?

Please let me know if I am missing anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is! If you calculate the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ (what apparently you were able to do), and these two distributions coincide, then we say that the two random variables are identically distributed.
For it to be mathematically rigorous, this depends on your calculation of the respective probabilities.